# I am unsure on how to make this print more sets of results

Tags: python

I am taking my first coding class and for this assignment I need to essentially make the powerball lottery. Where I am getting stuck is making the results more than one set of six numbers. I am not sure how to proceed. The requirements are as follows:

The first five can be any number from 1 to 69
The final number, the powerball, is from 1 to 26
Let’s write a program that simulates Powerball. The details:

For the first five numbers, each number can only appear once
The final number could be a repeat of one of the first five
Use Top-Down Design techniques to implement your simulation:
Print Intro
Ask how many draws to simulate – 
Simulate  draws
draw the five numbers
draw the Powerball
print the draw

This is what I have so far:

```
def printIntro():
        print("This program simulates the powerball")

def getInput():
        return int(input("How many draws should we simulate? "))
        
    
def runDraws(n_draws):
        #for n in n_draws:
                results = []
                for i in range(5):
                        number = r.randint(1,69)
                        while (number in results):
                                number = r.randint(1,69)
                        results.append(number)
                results.sort()
                results.append(r.randint(1,26))

                return results
                

def printResults(results):
    #for i in range(6,1):
        print(results)

import random as r

def main():
    printIntro()
    n_draws= getInput()
    results= runDraws(n_draws)
    printResults(results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help would certainly be appreciated!

Comment: Why not just `for n in n_draws:` / `printResults( runDraws() )` in your main?  Let the function handle ONE thing.  Let the mainline code decide how many times.

Comment: Also, the way you're picking random numbers is not evenly distributed.  You might consider doing `balls = list(range(69))` / `random.shuffle(balls)` then take the first 5.  And be sure to add 1.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close, but I think breaking up the draw and multiple draw logic may help.

- `random.sample` selects `k` elements from the list, by definition all different.
- `random.choice` selects one element from the list.
- A `range()` includes the first number, and excludes the last. Aka `range(0, 2)` is similar to `[0, 1]`.

```
import random

def printIntro():
    print("This program simulates the powerball")

def getInput():
    return int(input("How many draws should we simulate? "))

def draw5plus1():
    pos_values = range(1, 70)
    draw = random.sample(pos_values, 5)
    draw.append(random.choice(range(1, 27)))
    return draw

def runDraws(n_draws):
    results = []
    for i in range(n_draws):
        result = draw5plus1()
        results.append(result)
    return results

def printResults(results):
    for result in results:
        print(result)  
                
def main():
    printIntro()
    n_draws = getInput()
    results = runDraws(n_draws)
    printResults(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you Tim Roberts and BeRT2me for the assistance. You guys are lifesavers. I also appreciate the different angles you took on this that differed from me.